# How to refer to an Excel table column by name when table changes over time

Tags: excel

Short question:  Is there a way to get a formula that references a column in an Excel table to always refer to only the column with that name?  This is a straight-up formula question, not VBA-related.

**Formula:**

```
=COUNTIFS(Table35[[dc]:[dc]],$A6)
```

In this case column A has a data center name in it.  Table 35 is the output of another program that produces data for an ETL and also most of the same data for this spreadsheet that is used for both analysis and status reporting.

**Problem**

Due to the nature of analysis, the shape of the data changes.  It seems like about once a week there is another variable (column) that needs to be added to the ETL and analysis.  I've simply been copying the program output, going to the upper left hand of the table and pasting.  For all of my PivotTable analysis of this data it works exactly the way I want it to.

The problem happens to my dashboard built with various Countifs() formulas like the one above.  My initial expectation of behavior is that by referencing the data (first by column name and now as a range of columns that contain only one column of data) that Countifs() would select the data based on column header value (much like using vlookup() + match() together).

Instead what happens is that when a column gets added the names in all of my formulas change.  It appears the internal representation essentially says I want column #N.  No matter what data happens to be in column N, that is what shows up.  So for example, [dc] above turns into [CS Windows Error Message]

Is there any way to indicate that I want the column named "dc" regardless of where in the table dc is located?  Even the great and omniscient Google has failed me on this one.  Help appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour. If columns are inserted/removed, the formula still refers to the named column. You use a peculiar way to address the table column. How does this work: `=COUNTIFS(Table1[dc],$A6)`

Comment: I started out with that notation.  I was having the problem.  The notation I switched to is intended to select a range of columns.  One Excel "trick" that I read about suggested that as a workaround.  It didn't work.

Comment: Make a table with two columns labled "a" and "c".  Add a little data and do a countifs() for any values = 1 in Table1[c].  Now make a separate set of data (not a table) with 3 columns "a", "b", and "c".  Copy that.  Select the upper left of your table and paste.  You will now have a table with all 3 column headers.  (and in my case, the data in "a" and "c" are the same.  But the problem is that when the data gets pasted, the formula that used to refer to Table1[c] now refers to Table1[b]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the table reference into the Indirect function. That will preserve the column name and return the correct value.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table1[dc]"),2)
```

or, with your formula

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table35[[dc]:[dc]]"),$A6)
```

Comment: Perfect!.  I don't know the internals, but clearly a string literal isn't going to change wheras the table object reference was being evaluated and stored in a manner that did not rely on column name.